# How to add css browser compatible tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

I am using scrollmagic js for on scroll animation. I gave shadow to png file and add to jquery code. but it'showing error ( Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -).Thanks for help.

```
var tween = TweenMax.to(elemTo, 1, {
            -webkit-filter: 'drop-shadow(0px 10px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12))'
        });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to. jQuery takes care of vendor prefixes automatically.

Comment: The syntax error you get is caused by `-webkit-filter`. You can quote it to get rid of the syntax error. Thus, `'-webkit-filter': '...'`.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbrrfqgr/) (I darkened the boxShadow for emphasis here)

You can include your target element in quotation marks. The hyphen in the vendor prefix is what's causing your unexpected token error. See if this works better:

```
TweenMax.to(".someClass", 1, {
     boxShadow:"0px 10px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)"
});
```

You can also just add the css key, curly brackets, and quotation marks to get it working:

```
TweenMax.to(".someClass", 1, {
     css: {'-webkit-filter': 'drop-shadow(0px 10px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12))'}
});
```